# Restrict Landscape Access

Tags: landscape

Is it possible to restrict access of Landscape account to corporate network only? In other words I want to check if its possible to have our Landscape account only accessible from certain networks and not from anywhere outside corporate network.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it hosted at Canonical or on your premises?

Answer (score 0):

Most institutions handle that kind of functionality independent of any particular application, generally at the firewall level. 
Check with your network team about implementing policies to a particular IP/Network.